# How to destroy a session an hour or day after a user exit site

Tags: php, session

I have an admin page where some users can have access to but I want that whenever they leave the site or close the tab for about an hour or a day the session should be destroyed so as not to allow someone else.

Comment: if you talk about th `$_SESSION`  variable, all value in it will be destroyed (immediately) once the user close the browser.

Comment: @GNassro so you can't set a time limit for it to destroy after a user leaves the page

Comment: with $_SESSION directerly you CAN'T, but you can do some trick, like to store the session you want to keep it in a databese and specific the delay you want, then if the user open again the website, the system you create must check if passed 1hour or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are searching for is `$_COOKIE`. There you can define how long the Variable is saved etc. The only thing you will have to consider is that the values are stored locally and not on the server. If you want to achieve that, you can create a Cookie-Key system similar to the one PHP uses to save the Session data on the Server. In that Case the User would get a key, saved as a cookie and the data is stored on the server under that key.

Comment: i think you talked about `$_COOKIE` not `$_COOKIES`, and `$_COOKIES` is for retreive value created by [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), that can create only coockie with string value

Comment: and coockie not a good solution if the session values he looking for to saved are sensitive information

Comment: That is why I said that sensitive stuff should be saved on the server.